# Primary Key Constraint error while using insert query in java and SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, database

I have a java application that inserts records into the database from the textboxes. The problem is that when i click ADD it gives the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__customer__A1B71F90E76B7658'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.customer'. The duplicate key value is (5)

There is no duplication in my table and i cannot understand what to do. This is the first time i have encountred this error. No column in my database allows `null` and `cust_id` is a foreign key in another table. Here is my code

```html
stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
String sql = "insert into customer (cust_id, cust_name, father_name, birth_date, CNIC, city, card_num, acc_num, bank_name, address, email, ph_num) values ( " + String.valueOf(txtcust_id1.getText()) + ",'" + txtcust_name1.getText()
+ "','" + txtf_name1.getText() + "','" + txtb_date1.getText() + "','" + txtcnic1.getText() + "','" + txtcity1.getText() + "','" + txtcard_num1.getText() + "','" + txtacc_num1.getText() + "','" + txtb_n1.getText() + "','" + txtadd1.getText() + "','" +
txtemail1.getText() + "','" + txtph_num1.getText() + "' )"; 

stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 

System.out.println("Successful"); 

int rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 

String msg = "Insert Query Execution Failed"; 

if(rowsAffected > 0) { 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Query Successful"); 
} 
else { 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg, "Execution Alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
}
```

i can't use parametric query because i can't seem to handle date and money in it.

Comment: There is no duplication because the constraint precisely prevents you from creating one. You're trying to insert a PK (5) that already exists, and that causes the exception you get.

Comment: yes i know that but my database is empty. there is not a single record in it.

Comment: Then you're probably inserting the same value twice in the same transaction. The exception causes the transaction to rollback, and leaves the database empty. Or you're not using the database you thing you're using.

Comment: ok i will crate the database again then post what happens

Comment: nope saying the same thing

Comment: Nope what? You code has a bug. Find it. If the database tells you that you're inserting a PK that already exists, trust it. It's true. If you want us to help you find a bug in your code, we will need your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does:

```
stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 
System.out.println("Successful"); 
int rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

So it executes the same SQL, containing a hard-coded primary key, twice. That's why you get this exception.

BTW, your code is extremely fragile (just try adding an apostrophe in one of the strings you're inserting) , and a good candidate for a SQL injection attack. Learn about [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: ok.. i guess that's what happening.. so then how do i set the flag to know if it was successful or not? and i know about prepared statements. but i don't know what to do about setDate